Kendo UI for Angular kendo-upload component UI not styled properly
I'm working with Kendo UI for Angular, and am trying to make use of the kendo-upload component.
Component itself works as expected, however I have an issue with how it is displayed.
I've attached an image bellow of how the upload component is rendered.
kendo-upload component
What bothers me, is the insufficient spacing between icon and "Done" text as well as the scrollbar in the uploaded files section.
Does anyone know how can I work around this? I'm using the current latest version 16.7.1
I've tried switching versions, no success with that either.
